# How to validate host name \ domain name in Linux - C++

Tags: c++, linux, validation, dns

How can I validate host name \ domain name in Linux, C++?

In Windows I use for this purpose DnsValidateName - is there a good replacement for that in Linux GCC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use some reqular expressions. Take one of [these proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128168/validation-for-url-domain-using-regex-rails)
with some [regex library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use).