# Terraform Replace Regex not working correctly

Tags: regex, terraform

I have a regex to replace any non word characters, underscores or spaces in one of my variables to sanitise the name to pass it to Route53.

It is replacing non alphanumeric and underscores but it is getting stuck on spaces.

I know the regex is `\s` for whitespaces but it seems to be ignoring it when the Terraform plan runs but if I run it through a regex checker it works fine.

```
identifier        = "qa-${lower(replace(var.dns_name,"/\\W|_|\\s/","-"))}"
```

Comment: FYI, `\s` is not even required in this case because `\W` already includes it.

Comment: Even if I remove the `\s` it still breaks Terraform when theres a space in the name

Comment: Yes, I expected that, that was just a side note. Your regex seems straight-forward to me, so this is most likely a problem with Terraform. Maybe someone with experience in Terraform can help you.

Comment: @Luke - what does `plan` show you? 'computed'? 
What happens if you run `apply`?

Answer (score 4):

I used your regex in Terraform v0.12.21 and tested it with spaces and various special characters:

```
dns_name = "abc DEF 123 ~'`!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\\{}|;':\\./<>?\"\\'.com" 
identifier = "${lower(replace(var.dns_name,"/\\W|_|\\s/","-"))}"
```

and `terraform plan` showed that the regex correctly replaced anything other than letters, numbers, or hyphens with hyphens, which seems to be a what you needed for Route 53:

```
"abc-def-123-------------------------------------com"
```

But also be aware that domain names might not be able to contain two consecutive hyphens (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468309/can-domain-name-have-two-continuous-hyphens)).

Comment: "/\\W|_|\\s/" this saved my day. even though I didn't understand meaning of "|_|".

Comment: It seems `\W` does not match underscores: https://regex101.com/r/AWD8BA/2

Comment: @SNR, it means "or" ("non-word char or vertical line or space")