# Validate the structure of an url having or not http/https - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I validate that the structure of a url is correct ?, the urls may or may not contain http or https.

For example:

- www.google.com - is valid
- https://www.google.com - is valid
- www.google,com - is invalid
- www.google - is invalid

I try the code of this question:

[Validation for URL/Domain using Regex? (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128168/validation-for-url-domain-using-regex-rails)

```
validates :url_soporte, :url_privacidad, :web_site, :format => {
      :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix,
      :message => 'You provided invalid URL'
  }, :allow_blank => true
```

I get this error:

> The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $),
>   which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or
>   forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

and URI.regexp does not work for me

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things with a regex?

You could have a custom validator that just created a URI resource and confirmed that it has a host?

```
def validate_url(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)

  # raise errors if uri.host is nil
end
```

This way you can leave the `uri` package to worry about whether you have a valid domain in your URL, rather than trying to replicate the regex yourself.